# CSS Paragraph wrap to next line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap a paragraph text to the next line when the browser-window is shrinked. Currently, it stays in the same place and a horizontal scroll bar appears when the browser window shrinks beyond the paragraph text.

I tried CSS3 text-wrap property but it didn't work, or maybe I didn't use it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your CSS:

```
#header { 
 background: url("http://www.domainandseo.com/portfolio/page-view/images/header-bg.jpg") no-repeat transparent;
 min-height: 109px;
 /* width: 928px; *///  <-- remove this line
}

.header-content { 
 bottom: 15px;
 clear: both;
 margin-left: 190px;
 position: relative;
 /* width: 106%; *///  <-- remove this line
}
```

**Explanation:**
Removing the `width: 928px` from `#header` will cause the header to become `100%` wide, which means "as wide as the browser, so shrink when the browser gets smaller". Removing the `width: 106%` from `#header-content` makes it as wide as it's parent `#header`.

*A side note: using widths that are more than 100% are generally a bad idea, they present strange layout issues that are hard to trace and usually it means that elements end up just outside the viewport, which is almost always undesirable.*

Comment: Thanks...This ^ along with using a fixed width container for the menu for layout reasons works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your #header div set to a fixed width.  If you want it to wrap with the browser, set the width using percentages.

Comment: I'm using a fixed background image for the header. When I convert it to percentages, and the browser-size is decreased, the background image seems to get cropped. Any workaround to that?

Comment: Google 'CSS background-size cover'